# Google Analytics API Cost Data Upload stuck

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-java-client

I followed [Management API - Daily Upload Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtDailyUploadGuide) and created installed java application to *upload Cost Data* to Google Analytics. But It somehow doesn't work. I have `Analytics` service created authorized with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics` scope and now I want to upload some Cost Data.

I did it according to mentioned Guide like this.

```java
File file = new File("data.csv");
InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent('application/octet-stream', new FileInputStream(file));
mediaContent.setLength(file.length());

// You can ignore following three lines... those are there to make sure Analytics service works.
Accounts accounts = analytics.management().accounts().list().execute();
Account account = accounts.getItems().get(0);
System.out.println("Account ID is: " + account.getId());

Analytics.Management management = analytics.management();
Analytics.Management.DailyUploads dailyUploads = management.dailyUploads();

// Here it gets stuck!
Analytics.Management.DailyUploads.Upload upload = dailyUploads.upload("AccountID",
  "PropertyID", "CustomDataSourceID", "yyyy-MM-dd", 1, "cost", mediaContent);

upload.setReset(true);
DailyUploadAppend append = upload.execute();
```

I added some lines to retrieve `Accounts` and print *AccountID* of the first `Account`... just to be sure that `Analytics service` works.
And it does. I am able to get *AccountID* but I am not able to upload my Cost Data. I don't know what is wrong... but it gets stuck when it tries to get the `Upload` object.

It doesn't throw Exception. It just holds there and does nothing. Is there something I am missing? I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I downloaded java client library 1.13.2. from [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/)

Java Client Library doesn't contain Management API `google-api-services-analytics-v3` So I downloaded the newest from [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/com/google/?repo=mavenrepo#google%2Fapis%2Fgoogle-api-services-analytics) it was *v3-rev20-1.8.0-beta*

I found both in Developer Guide [client libraries link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtLibraries)

But today I found *rev26-1.13.2-beta* [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Google_Analytics_API) and used it in my solution. Now Everything works, so it was just an incompatibility issue caused by misleading links in Developer Guide.

**EDIT**

For people struggling with this problem in the future. Be sure your libraries are compatible. As you can see I was able to GET AccountID of the first Account so I thought everything was OK, but it wasn't. There are many missleading links in Google Guides and what I found I reported via Google Groups. For me there was a hint. I had *google-api-java-client-**1.13.2**-beta* and *google-api-services-analytics-v3-rev20-**1.8.0**-beta*.

But problem is there was no sign of newer version... I downloaded what I thought was the newest from their mercurial repository. And still there was a newer version accessible only from one link somewhere deep in developers guide. I hope it will be better in the future.

Comment: Looks like a broken link on https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtLibraries .  We should instead be pointing to https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Google_Analytics_API .  I will try to get that fixed.